# How to export the fields of an embedded document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My doc:

```
db.org.insert({
  "id" : 28,
  "organisation" : "Mickey Mouse company",
  "country" : "US",
  "contactpersons" : [{
      "title" : "",
      "typecontact" : "D",
      "mobilenumber" : "757784854",
      "firstname" : "Mickey",
      "lastname" : "Mouse",
      "emailaddress" : "mickey@mouse.com"
    },
    {
      "title" : "",
      "typecontact" : "E",
      "mobilenumber" : "757784854",
      "firstname" : "Donald",
      "lastname" : "Duck",
      "emailaddress" : "donald@duck.com"
    }],
  "modifieddate" : "2013-11-21T16:04:49+0100"
});
```

My query:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db sample --collection org --type csv --fields country,contactpersons.0.firstname,contactpersons.0.emailaddress --out D:\info_docs\org.csv
```

By this query, I'm able to get only the first document values of the contactpersons.But, I'm trying to export the second document values also.

How can I resolve this issue ? Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting exactly the first document in `contactpersons` because you are only exporting the first element of the array (`contactpersons.0.firstname`). `mongoexport` can't export several or all elements of an array, so what you need to do is to unwind the array and save it in another collection. You can do this with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

First, do an `$unwind` of contactpersons, then `$project` the fields you want to use (in your example, `country` and `contactpersons`), and finally save the output in a new collection with `$out`.

```
db.org.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$contactpersons'},
  {$project: {_id: 0, org_id: '$id', contacts: '$contactpersons', country: 1}},
  {$out: 'aggregate_org'}
])
```

Now you can do a mongoexport of `contacts` (which is the result of the `$unwind` of `contactpersons`) and `country`.

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db sample --collection aggregate_org --type=csv --fields country,contacts.firstname,contacts.emailaddress --out D:\info_docs\org.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, it is using a dummy collection right. Instead of that can we write the javascript code to iterate the embedded document and use the same .js file in the mongoexport command

Comment: Right, in that case you're using a new dummy collection to store the result of the unwind. I'm not sure how you could do it with a javascript code; in the end you'd have to unwind the array anyway.